# How to save cursor position in TCL?

Tags: tcl

How do I save the cursor position into a variable in TCL ?

The best I can come up with is:

```
set tty [open /dev/tty w]
puts $tty "\033\[6n"
close $tty

set position [read stdin]
puts $position
```

but I cannot capture the output.

I have also tried using `::term::ansi::send::qcp` from Tcllib but get the same problem.

(FYI I tried to model the above TCL on a PHP answer from [How to get cursor position with PHP-CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55892416/how-to-get-cursor-position-with-php-cli)).

Comment: You might look into one of the tcl curses libraries.

Answer (score 1):

It's *tricky* to get this right, as we need to read a partial line and it's not yielded by the terminal implementation immediately. After experimenting a bit, the most reliable approach that I found was this:

```sh
proc readbits {{chan stdin}} {
    set s ""
    while {![eof $chan]} {
        set c [read $chan 1]
        append s $c
        if {$c eq "R"} break
    }
    return $s
}

proc getcur {} {
    puts -nonewline "\u001b\[6n"
    flush stdout
    scan [readbits] "\u001b\[%d;%dR"
}

# Must be in raw+noecho mode for this to work!
exec stty raw -echo
puts [getcur]
# Restore normal mode
exec stty -raw echo
```

In Tcl 8.7, you can use: `fconfigure stdin -mode raw` and `fconfigure stdin -mode normal` in place of those `exec stty` calls.

Comment: The escape sequence to request the information was from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34746634/termcaps-get-cursor-position and I've tested this on macOS, but it should also work on Linux and other POSIX.